# How to access an encrypted external SD card with all apps?

Tags: samsung, external-sd, encryption

I have encrypted both the device and the external SD card of a previously unencrypted Samsung phone running Android 6.0.1.

After encrypting the SD card, apparently some apps can not access the files on the SD card unencrypted.

Specifically, image viewers, media players, some stock document viewers and MTP transfer *work*, i.e. they can acces the files decrypted. Howevery, a text editor, K9 mail, the Signal messenger, Open Keychain and some cloud sync apps can only acces the *encrypted file content*. This means I can not send the original, unencrypted file via email or messenger, and I can not edit local text files.

Expected behaviour would be that Android transparently decrypts and encrypts local file contents when an applications wants to read and write these.

- Is that a known problem? Maybe specific to Samsung?
- Do apps have to implement some special logic or functions to gain acces the unencrypted file contents via Android, i.e. is that a bug that the respective developers can fix?
- And is there a way I can provide the unencrypted file contents to any app?